# Using Java EE classes without installing SDK?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have already installed standard Java SE JDK into my system. Now I need to gain access to Java EE classes like `javax.jms.*`.

Thing is, I don't want to install GlassFish or other kind of trash together with it (SDK). I just need to extend my Java SE with EE classes. Is this possible, or do I have to really go through installing SDK s**t?

Answer (score 2):

Most EE libraries are available separately, either through [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) (search on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/)) or from [java.net](http://www.java.net/projects).

JMS can be downloaded separately from [its own site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jms/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Set up your project to build with Maven, where you have all the Java EE components split into small Java packages such as javax.mail:mail, javax.servlet:servlet-api, etc. This way you don't need to install a bunch of crap, nor do you need to know the tons of libaries they depend on, because they're fetched for you.